# What hyperparameter values does the LDA mallet model use by default? Is it true that the formula to calculate alpha = 5.0/n(topics)?

Tags: python, nlp, lda, dirichlet

I am trying to figure out the default $\alpha$ & $\eta$ values used by mallet LDA, but there is not a lot of information on this. I did find a couple of answers, with no proper references, saying that symmetric $\alpha$ can be calculated with `5.0/num_topics`? Why is that? Why can't I use `1.0/num_topics` to calculate the symmetric $\alpha$, just like in standard LDA? Can someone please help me understand and link me to references?

Thanks in advance.